# Regular expression with danish phone number

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write a regular expression so I can replace following phone numbers with a link:

```
first
+45 55 44 33 22
second
+4555443322
third
+45 55443322
fourth
55443322
and last
55 44 33 22
```

Currently my regular expression looks like this:

```
Regex phoneRegex = new Regex(@"[0-9]{8}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex phoneRegexInternation = new Regex(@"(?:\+\[0-9]{10})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex phoneRegexwithSpace = new Regex(@"[0-9]{2}\s*[0-9]{2}\s*[0-9]{2}\s*[0-9]{2}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex phoneRegexInternationWithSpaceAfterAreaCode = new Regex(@"(\+?[0-9]{2})\s*[0-9]{8}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex phoneRegexwithSpaceInternational = new Regex(@"(\+?[0-9]{2})\s*[0-9]{2}\s*[0-9]{2}\s*[0-9]{2}\s*[0-9]{2}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But my result is this:

```
first +Acceptere opgaven for at se telefonnummer. 22 second +Acceptere opgaven for at se telefonnummer.22 third +45 Acceptere opgaven for at se telefonnummer. fourth Acceptere opgaven for at se telefonnummer. and last Acceptere opgaven for at se telefonnummer.
```

"Acceptere opgaven for at se telefonnummer" is a danish expression for accept the assignment to see the phonenumber and it's a link, but as you can se it's not hiding the plus sign and a few of the numbers correctly.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [`^(?:(?<local>(?:\d ?){8})|(?<international>\+(?:\d ?){10}))`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3clocal%3e%28%3f%3a%5cd+%3f%29%7b8%7d%29%7c%28%3f%3cinternational%3e%5c%2b%28%3f%3a%5cd+%3f%29%7b10%7d%29%29&i=first%0d%0a%2b45+55+44+33+22%0d%0asecond%0d%0a%2b4555443322%0d%0athird%0d%0a%2b45+55443322%0d%0afourth%0d%0a55443322%0d%0aand+last%0d%0a55+44+33+22&o=m)?

Comment: `@"\+?(\d{2} ?){4,5}"`

Comment: It looks like you're using the regex to _Validate_ the phone number. But, how can you do that eh? To just match the 8 or 10  digits, use `\+?(?:\h*\d){8}(?:(?:\h*\d){2})?` and that's all you need.

Comment: `\+?(?:\h*\d){8}(?:(?:\h*\d){2})?` is not working, i'm giving following error when trying to use:
`parsing "\+?(?:\h*\d){8}(?:(?:\h*\d){2})?" - Unrecognized escape sequence \h.`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov thank you vey much, you saved my day, your expression was just the right one that helped me get where it has to go, i now regonize all of the variants of the phonenumber, please send me an answer and i will accept it, but will you please explaine what it's happening in the expression for me so i can understand it and learn from it :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov gave me this yesterday @"\+?(\d{2} ?){4,5}" and it's works like a charm, but a little adjustment needed, what if some one tries to write the phone number like this: + 4 5 5 5 4 4 3 3 2 2 or like so + 4.5 5.5.4.4.3.3.2.2 it needs to cache all of the possibilities for people to write a phone number so i can be readed, any suggestions?

Comment: Try `@"\+?(\d[. ]?){8,10}"`. I very bad speak English, so without explanation.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov thank you very much, worked like i expected it to :) please post an answer so i can end this post :)

Comment: `Unrecognized escape sequence \h` - it's the same as `[^\S\r\n]`

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = @"first
+45 55 44 33 22
second
+4555443322
third
+45 55443322
fourth
55443322
and last
55 44 33 22";

var regex = new Regex(@"(?<inter>\+45\s?)?(?<part1>\d{2})\s?(?<part2>\d{2})\s?(?<part2>\d{2})\s?(?<part4>\d{2})");
var matches = regex.Matches(input);

var output = new StringBuilder();
var lastindex = 0; 
var index = 0;
foreach (Match m in matches){
    index = m.Index;
    output.Append(input.Substring(lastindex, index - lastindex));

    var phone = $"+45{m.Groups["part1"]}{m.Groups["part2"]}{m.Groups["part3"]}{m.Groups["part4"]}";
    output.Append($"<a href=\"#\" data-original=\"{m.Value}\" data-generic=\"{phone}\">Acceptere opgaven for at se telefonnummer</a>");

    lastindex = m.Index + m.Length;
}

Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
```

Result is:

```
first
<a href="#" data-original="+45 55 44 33 22" data-generic="+45553322">Acceptere opgaven for at se telefonnummer</a>
second
<a href="#" data-original="+4555443322" data-generic="+45553322">Acceptere opgaven for at se telefonnummer</a>
third
<a href="#" data-original="+45 55443322" data-generic="+45553322">Acceptere opgaven for at se telefonnummer</a>
fourth
<a href="#" data-original="55443322" data-generic="+45553322">Acceptere opgaven for at se telefonnummer</a>
and last
<a href="#" data-original="55 44 33 22" data-generic="+45553322">Acceptere opgaven for at se telefonnummer</a>
```

Comment: not exactley what i was looking for, i am looking for the right expressions for each different phone number version, i still like to use the method i allready uses :)

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing how you are applying those regular expressions, it is difficult to determine what you are doing.  It would also be helpful to know exactly what you are expecting to see.  That said, I will do my best to answer.

Based on the regular expressions, input, and output, it seems like you may be inadvertently applying the wrong regular expressions to the wrong inputs.  As previously mentioned, without seeing exactly how you are using them, we cannot know.  Notice that phoneRegexWithSpace will match the very first input, except for the + and 22, which both pop up unwanted in your output.

To correct it, you can do a few things:

1. Ensure that each expression can *only* match the specific case you want to match.  You can use look-behinds and look-aheads to help with that.  See: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html
2. Craft a single regular expression which can match any permutation.  For example, you can make the prefix optional to combine phoneRegexWithSpace with phoneRegexwithSpaceInternational
3. If you are testing one number at a time, make sure you match against the more inclusive expressions first.  For example, test for phoneRegexwithSpaceInternational before you test for phoneRegexWithSpace